# Extremely long footnotes running off page

Tags: footnotes, margins, bigfoot

I'm very very new to latex, in fact I'm only using it for a writing piece for its ability to make footnotes in footnotes. The main text is only one sentence, with the footnotes running for about 6 pages underneath (using bigfoot). I've noticed that on the first page, the page with the main text, the footnotes run off the page and then randomly start again as normal for the next 5 pages.

I've tried \providecommand{\footfudgefiddle}{100} up {64} and nothing happened. I've seen similar questions on here about it but don't really understand what's going on.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!!

[image: here is a dummy text.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}

\makeatletter
\let\@makefntext@orig\@makefntext
\FootnoteSpecific{B}\def\@makefntext{\@makefntext@orig\tiny}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Dummy Text}
\date{}
\maketitle

\pagebreak

\centerline{This\footnoteA{This is a\footnoteB{this is a sub-footnote} footnote x1000} } is \footnoteA{This is another footnote x1000} my main text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE!  What a huge footnote! Can you show an document example (with dummy text), which show your problem? I', curios ...

Comment: How about an endnote instead of a multipage footnote?

Comment: @Zarko of course! I have added it to the post. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: Could you also provide a minimum working example (MWE) so that we know what you are doing now and go from there?

Comment: @cktai done! Thanks!

Comment: I took a look at it and as far as I can tell, this is a problem of the bigfoot package. It tends to create footnotes that run off the page, even if there are no embedded footnotes.